# Yocto and Linux

Tags: linux

I am following the instructions here:

http://www.rocketboards.org/foswiki/Documentation/AlteraSoCDevelopmentBoardYoctoGettingStarted

I run this command

```
bitbake virtual/kernel
```

Everything works fine except it does not create a  socfpga_cyclone5.dtb

I run this command, which should be the same

```
bitbake altera-image
```

And I get the error

```
ERROR: Multiple .bb files are due to be built which each provide virtual/kernel (/home/bobo/yocto/meta-altera/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-altera_3.11.bb /home/bobo/yocto/meta-altera/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-altera-dist.bb).
```

This usually means one provides something the other doesn't and should.

Does anyone know how to create that .dtb file or fix the second command?  Up to that point I had no errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your .dtb file should be coming from the Altera software flow through Qsys and that is the one you should use, rather than the one that is created from the Yocto build system.

The Yocto build system will not be aware of the FPGA design and hence that .dtb won't be useful.

The error you're getting is mostly due to conflicting meta files.  Sometimes a target might have multiple providers. A common example is "virtual/kernel", which is provided by each kernel recipe. Each machine often selects the best kernel provider by using a line similar to the following in the **machine configuration file**, which should be somewhere in 
poky/meta-altera/conf/machine/your-machine.conf:

```
 PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-altera-3.11"
```